Ubuntu 22 screen automatically working and flickering
I am using Ubuntu 22 and since I installed ubuntu I am facing a problem that my screen gets working automatically whenever I open laptop, like it automatically open the upper section (i.e bluetooth or poweroption), sometimes if I am on browser it automaticaclly turn off the browser or open random sections of browser. Also, when I open browser and select my profile, screen flickers heavily.
I have tried some things but nothing is working. I am using Lenevo X1 Carbon and the machine is touch screen. Please help me out
